# No se muestran los datos en la vista editar.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Aquí el código que he hecho, pero no logro hacer que los datos que quiero editar aparezcan, aparecen los datos que están en la misma tabla, Pero no los datos que están en otra tabla las cuales tienen relación con la tabla principal, haciendo uso del viewbag.

Controlador:

```
public ActionResult Edit(decimal id = 0)
    {

        USUARIO usuario = db.USUARIO.Find(id);
        if (datos == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }


        var area = db.AREA.Where(x => x.FKUSUARIO == id);
        foreach (var xarea in areas)
        {
            ViewBag.areas = xarea.AREA1;
        }
        var grado = db.GRADOEST.Where(z => z.FKUSUARIO == id);
        foreach (var zgrado in grados)
        {
            ViewBag.grados = zgrado.GRADOESTUDIO;
        }

            return View(usuario);
        }
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(USUARIO usuario)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();               
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(usuario);
    }
```

Vista editar:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
       {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

       <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AREA1, "AREA")
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AREA1, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AREA1)
       </div>
     <div class="editor-label">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GRADOESTUDIO, "GRADO DE ESTUDIO")
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GRADOESTUDIO, new { @class = "form-control" })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GRADOESTUDIO)
         </div>
        <footer>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                ACTUALIZAR DATOS
            </button>
        </footer>
      }
```

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

Comment: Porqué escribes todo con mayúsculas

Answer (score 0):

Ojo: tienes unos errores en el codigo mejoralo para poder ayudarte en la respuesta.

Primero:
esto no lo puedes hacer

```
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GRADOESTUDIO, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

el problema es q GRADOESTUDIO no es una propiedad de tu modelo usuario, recuerda q el modelo q pasas a la vista es usuario.
Te aconsejo q castear el viewbag, para q asi el razor sepa q estas pasando datos de una entidad o un modelo.